# 'This is how I look like' OR 'This is how do I look like'

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

For question, we will usually put 'do' in front of verb, but the sentences above are not questions. So, should I omit the 'do'?

Comment: "This is *what* I look like" or "this is how I look".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement is incorrectly formed. If you use 'how' you should leave out 'like', if you use 'like' you should replace 'how' with 'what'. This gives you the statements

> **This is how I look.**

or

> **This is what I look like**.

For a statement you shouldn't use 'do' on either case

---

If you want a general question you can use either of the following which are **inversions** of the statements with 'do' inserted.

> **How do I look?**

or

> **What do I look like?**

If you have more specific concerns you can say

> **Do I look presentable ?** (You can replace 'presentable' with any one of a large number of words or phrases such as 'acceptable', 'OK', 'a mess', 'ill' or 'terrible').

There are other ways of asking the same question or making the same statement but this answer is already complex enough.

The main point is that you should not combine 'how' and 'like' in the way you did in your question header. This is because they perform different but parallel functions: 'like' is an implied comparison ('I look like the person in this photograph' for example) whereas 'how' is an abstract statement or question with no comparison.